# Replace each character of string with new character string

Tags: c#

The c# program I'm developing checks the first character of user input and if it starts with `.` (dot) I want to replace each character of user input with pacified character string while the user is writing, but I'm getting the error

> Index out of bounds exception

My code:

```
if (textBox1.Text.StartWith(".")) {
    string MyText = "Hello World";
    int x = 0;
    string NewText;
    while (x <= MyText.Length) {
        NewText = textBox1.Text.Replace(textBox1.Text[x], MyText[x]);
        TextBox1.Text = NewText;
        x++;
    }
}
```

Comment: `x<=MyText.Length` goes out of bounds. Arrays are 0 indexed.

Answer (score 3):

You're overrunning the bounds of the string, replace:

```
while (x <= MyText.Length) {
```

with

```
while (x < MyText.Length) {
```

Answer (score 2):

```
while(x < MyText.Length)
```

or

```
while(x <= MyText.Length - 1)
```

If array has length = x, its last index is x-1, because array starts from 0 index

Comment: @Elias You should check textBox1.Text.Length also.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right (there're no samples in question), I suggest using *Linq* which is straitforward; try using *modular arimethics* - `index % MyText.Length` to avoid index problems

```
string source = ".My Secret Message for Test";
string MyText = "Hello World";

// If user input starts with dot
if (source.StartsWith("."))
  source = string.Concat(source
    .Select((c, index) => MyText[index % MyText.Length])); 

TextBox1.Text = source;
```

Outcome:

```
   Hello WorldHello WorldHello
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all as @Daniell89 said:

use

```
while(x < MyText.Length)
```

Secondly:
You use x as an index not only for MyText but for textBox1.Text too. So you need to check that it is long enough.

you can do something like this:

```
while (x < Math.Min(MyText.Length, textBox1.Text.Length)
{
    NewText = textBox1.Text.Replace(textBox1.Text[x], MyText[x]);
    TextBox1.Text = NewText;
    x++;
}
```

But I think it would be better to use for statement here.